# hive external table on parquet not fetching data

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, parquet

I am trying to create a datapipeline where the incomng data is stored into parquet and i create and external hive table and users can query the hive table and retrieve data .I am able to save the parquet data and retrieve it directly but when i query the hive table its not returning any rows. I did the following test setup

--CREATE EXTERNAL HIVE TABLE 
create external table emp (
id  double,
hire_dt timestamp,
user string
)
stored as  parquet 
location   '/test/emp';

Now created dataframe on some data and saved to parquet .

---Create dataframe and insert  DATA

```
val employeeDf = Seq(("1", "2018-01-01","John"),("2","2018-12-01", "Adam")).toDF("id","hire_dt","user")
val schema = List(("id", "double"), ("hire_dt", "date"), ("user", "string"))
val newCols= schema.map ( x => col(x._1).cast(x._2)) 
val newDf = employeeDf.select(newCols:_*)
newDf.write.mode("append").parquet("/test/emp")
newDf.show 

--read the contents directly from parquet 
val sqlcontext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlcontext.read.parquet("/test/emp").show 

+---+----------+----+
| id|   hire_dt|user|
+---+----------+----+
|1.0|2018-01-01|John|
|2.0|2018-12-01|Adam|
+---+----------+----+

--read from the external hive table 
spark.sql("select  id,hire_dt,user from  emp").show(false)

+---+-------+----+
|id |hire_dt|user|
+---+-------+----+
+---+-------+----+
```

As shown above i am able to see the data if i read from parquet directly but not from hive .The question is what i am doing wrong here ? What  i am i doing wrong that the hive isnt getting the data. I thought msck repair may be a reason but i get error if i try to do msck repair table saying table not partitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this working with below chgn.

```
val dfTransformed = employeeDf.withColumn("id", employeeDf.col("id").cast(DoubleType))
            .withColumn("hire_dt", employeeDf.col("hire_dt".cast(TimestampType))
```

So basically the issue was datatype mismatch and some how the original code the cast doesn't seem to work. So i did an explicit cast  and then write it goes fine and able to query back as well.Logically both are doing the same not sure why the original code not working.

```
val employeeDf = Seq(("1", "2018-01-01","John"),("2","2018-12-01", "Adam")).toDF("id","hire_dt","user")

val dfTransformed = employeeDf.withColumn("id", employeeDf.col("id").cast(DoubleType))
    .withColumn("hire_dt", employeeDf.col("hire_dt".cast(TimestampType))

dfTransformed.write.mode("append").parquet("/test/emp")
dfTransformed.show 

--read the contents directly from parquet 
val sqlcontext=new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlcontext.read.parquet("/test/emp").show 

+---+----------+----+
| id|   hire_dt|user|
+---+----------+----+
|1.0|2018-01-01|John|
|2.0|2018-12-01|Adam|
+---+----------+----+

--read from the external hive table 
spark.sql("select  id,hire_dt,user from  emp").show(false)
+---+----------+----+
| id|   hire_dt|user|
+---+----------+----+
|1.0|2018-01-01|John|
|2.0|2018-12-01|Adam|
+---+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your create table statement, you have used location as /test/emp but while writing data, you are writing at /tenants/gwm/idr/emp. So you will not have data at /test/emp.

CREATE EXTERNAL HIVE TABLE create external table emp ( id double, hire_dt timestamp, user string ) stored as parquet location '/test/emp';

Please re-create external table as

CREATE EXTERNAL HIVE TABLE create external table emp ( id double, hire_dt timestamp, user string ) stored as parquet location '/tenants/gwm/idr/emp';

Comment: sorry that was a typo while posting as  i want to chng the path used in the offce network to a generic one .  just to confirm , the issue is still there .thnx for ur quick response though

Comment: you can try in your spark code to describe table emp to validate location. spark.sql("describe formatted emp").show(100,false)

Comment: this seems printing fine                                                                   col_name                     data_type                                   
id                           double                                         
hire_dt                      timestamp                                      
user                         string

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer given by Ramdev below, you also need to be cautious of using the correct datatype around date/timestamp; as '`date`' type is not supported by parquet when creating a hive table.

For that you can change the '`date`' type for column '`hire_dt`' to '`timestamp`'.

Otherwise there will be a mismatch in data you persisting through spark and trying to read in hive (or hive SQL). Keeping it to 'timestamp' at both places will resolve the issue. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried changing date to timestamp still it doesnt  return  any rows

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enableHiveSupport() in your sparkSession builder() statement. Are you able to connect to hive metastore? Try doing show tables/databases in your code to see if you can display tables present at your hive location?